# Livewire and CKEditor

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I'm trying to use some ritch text editors with livewire. I've used code from here
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-bind-ckeditor-value-to-laravel-livewire-component

but it gets error in console

> CKEditorError: this.viewElement.ownerDocument.body is null

My code:

```
<div
class="form-textarea w-full"
x-data
x-init="
    console.log($refs.myIdentifierHere)
    ClassicEditor.create($refs.myIdentifierHere)
    .then( function(editor){
        editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
        $dispatch('input', editor.getData())
        })
    })
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
"
wire:ignore
wire:key="myIdentifierHere"
x-ref="myIdentifierHere"
wire:model.debounce.9999999ms="description">{!! $description !!}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this error too. I've narrowed it down though such that I only have it happen when the ckeditor component is inside of an alpinejs element using x-show to hide it. (I have a form with tabs across the top to switch between the many inputs).

Outside of an alpinejs component, my ckeditor component, which looks identical to yours except for id's, works fine with livewire.